# Get enum value by name

Tags: c, enums

I have an enumeration, which contains hundreds of entries.

I will be getting the value of the enumeration as a string. Is there any way to convert the string into an enum value? Otherwise, I will end up using hundreds of if statements.

Consider

```
enum Colors { Red, Green, Blue, Yellow ... } there are more than 100 entries
```

I will be getting `"Red"` in a string variable,

```
String color = "Red"; // "Red" would be generated dynamically.
```

Normally we access the enum in the following way,
`Colors::Red`, `Colors::Blue` etc...
is there any way in which we can access it in a way something like this:

```
Colors::color; // i.e enumtype::stringVariable
```

In many posts here, it’s given that we can use map, but again while constructing map we will end up in using hundreds of `if`s.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: No, not like that. Also, what you’re talking about is not C.

Comment: The way to avoid it would be to use an actual table.

Comment: Actual table in the sense?? considering both c/cpp.

Comment: Well, one easy way would be to put each name into an array, assuming they’re sequential starting from 0.

Comment: again we cant avoid if statements.

Comment: Yes, we can. For example, using an array.

Comment: Your question is tagged C, but the `Colors::color` is a syntax error in C, and there is no predefined type called `String`. What language are you using? Is it C#?

Comment: Enums can be assigned values.  You could treat the first five letters of your color as digits of a base 26 number and convert that to base 10 for your enum value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting from String to Enum in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844728/converting-from-string-to-enum-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a C way of doing it, similar to Paddy's C++ map. The macro guarantees that the name and corresponding enum are tied together.

```
enum Colors { NoColor, Red, Green, Blue, Yellow };

enum Colors get_color(const char *s)
{
    const struct {
        char *name;
        enum Colors color;
    } colormap[] = {
#define Color(x) {#x, x}
        Color(Red),
        Color(Green),
        Color(Blue),
        Color(Yellow)
#undef Color
    };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof colormap / sizeof colormap[0]; ++i) {
        if (!strcmp(s, colormap[i].name)) {
            return colormap[i].color;
        }
    }
    return NoColor;
}
```

---

**EDIT**
As @sh1 suggested in a comment (which has now gone), you could use an X-macro to define the list of colors.  This avoids defining the list twice.  Here's the above example rewritten using an X-macro - thanks to sh1 for the hint:

```
#define COLORS  X(Red), X(Green), X(Blue), X(Yellow),

enum Colors {
    NoColor, 
#define X(x) x
    COLORS
#undef X
};

enum Colors get_color(const char *s)
{
    const struct {
        char *name;
        enum Colors color;
    } colormap[] = {
#define X(x) {#x, x}
        COLORS
#undef X
    };
...etc
```

Comment: Love this solution! Would it be a good idea to undefine `Color(x)` right after the `Color(Yellow)` statement to prevent unintended results in other parts of the code?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [X-macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) technique.  Transcribing almost directly from Wikipedia:

```
#define LIST_OF_COLORS \
    X(Red) \
    X(Green) \
    X(Blue) \
    X(Yellow)

#define X(name) name,
enum Colors { LIST_OF_COLORS };
#undef X

#define X(name) #name,
char const * const ColorName[] = { LIST_OF_COLORS };
#undef X
```

Because enums automatically assign values counting from zero, and we can't accidentally repeat the list in a different order when we create the name array, using the enum as the index into the `ColorName` array will always point directly to the corresponding word, and you don't have to search when mapping in that direction.  So:

```
printf("%s\n", ColorName[Red]);
```

Will print:

```
Red
```

And going the other way:

```
enum Color strtoColor(char const *name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ColorName) / sizeof(*ColorName); i++)
        if (strcmp(ColorName[i], name) == 0)
            return (enum Color)i;
    return -1;
}
```

---

*EDIT*

If you are using C++, then, Using X-macro on paddy's answer:

```
static std::map<string, enum Colors> colorMap;
void InitColorMap()
{
#define X(name) colorMap[#name] = name;
    LIST_OF_COLORS
#undef X
}
```

Or, stealing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138612/2417578), in C++11:

```
static std::map<string, enum Colors> colorMap =
{
#define X(name) { #name, name },
    LIST_OF_COLORS
#undef X
};
```

... or whatever.  That's not my language.

Comment: It's occurred to me that it's more useful to `#define LIST_OF_FOO(X) X(foo1) X(foo2)...`, because then you can instantiate things like `LIST_OF_FOO(STRINGIZE)` and define `STRINGIZE` just once for multiple lists.

Comment: Just [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57087772/2417578) that my previous comment is legal, and the question illustrates how to get more compact code when you have multiple enums to describe.  I should edit this answer, but I doubt I'll find the time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but if you are using pure C you could do the following:

```
char* stringArray[]={"Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow"};
```

Then you can find the matching string by looping over the array until you find a match:

```
for(ii = 0; ii < size(stringArray); ii++) {
  if (strcmp(inputString, stringArray[ii]) == 0) {
    // you found it!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you're using C or C++ here.

One way to sort this out is to use a macro with the stringize operator.  Something like this:

```
#define RegisterColor(c) colorMap[#c] = (c)
```

In this case, I've assumed something like a C++ `map`:

```
enum Colors { .... };
static std::map<string, enum Colors> colorMap;

void InitColorMap()
{
    RegisterColor(Red);
    RegisterColor(Green);
    RegisterColor(Blue);
    RegisterColor(Yellow);
    // ...
}
```

There is a little repetition, but if you need the `enum` you can't avoid that.

It's easy enough to use the same principle in C, using your own data structure.

Comment: If you're using a `std::map` there's no reason to involve the preprocessor at all, just set them `colorMap["Red"] = Red;`.

Comment: Sure, but now 'Red' appears thrice instead of twice.