# enumerating all enum names/values in C

Tags: c, enums

How can I enumerate all `enum` names and values in C to print it like

```
printf("Name: %s, value: %d\n", name, value);
```

?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to get for an enum name in C or looping through it. Enums are just constant values. Would you mind elaborating on the use case?

Comment: Something like `Enum.GetValues` or `Enum.GetNames` in C# - I'm just curious if it's possible in C.

Comment: No, it's not. C# has a notion of enum types in run time that C does not have. Just think of C enums as integer values. You can loop through the values in a normal for loop `for(i=FIRSTVALUE,i<LASTVALUE;i++){` assuming the values are sequential (usually the case).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get enum value by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070763/get-enum-value-by-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [**the X macro**](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-x-macro/228700289):

```
#define COLORS \
    X(Cred, "red") \
    X(Cblue, "blue") \
    X(Cgreen, "green")

#define X(a, b) a,
enum Color { COLORS };
#undef X


#define X(a, b) b,
static char *ColorStrings[] = { COLORS };
#undef X

printf("%s\n", ColorStrings[Cred]); // output: red
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least not directly. There are a few solutions though.

First, if you don't actually need the names, you can simply have an end marker in the enum, if values are sequential:

```
enum my_vals { FIRST, SECOND, LAST_my_vals };
...
for (enum my_vals it = FIRST ; it < LAST_my_vals ; ++it) {
    ....
}
```

But if you do need the names, you can adapt this question: [Get enum value by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070763/get-enum-value-by-name?rq=1)

Then you will have a array with all the values, and can iterate the array.