# Is it legal to pass the macro name to an X-Macro list

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, x-macros

It occurred to me that the following would be a preferable style of [X-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) trick:

```
#define LIST_OF_COLOURS(X) \
    X(RED) \
    X(GREEN) \
    X(BLUE)

#define LIST_OF_FRUIT(X) \
    X(APPLE) \
    X(ORANGE) \
    X(TOMATO)
```

Specifically, passing the `X` macro to the list, rather than undefining and redefining it every time the list is instantiated.  This allows:

```
#define X_LIST(x) x,
#define X_STRING_LIST(x) #x,
#define COMPREHENSIVE_SETUP(n, l)  \
    enum n { l(X_LIST) };  \
    char const* n##Names[] = { l(X_STRING_LIST) };

COMPREHENSIVE_SETUP(Colour, LIST_OF_COLOURS)
COMPREHENSIVE_SETUP(Fruit, LIST_OF_FRUIT)
```

But the problem is that I don't regularly see that idiom in the wild, and it's not what Wikipedia describes, even though it "seems to work" whenever I try it and feels much more convenient.

My question is, is this actually legal and fully defined, or am I relying on undefined behaviour?

Comment: Just came across this in the wild (libuv). Kinda blew my mind. I was only familiar with the x macros described in wikipedia. https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/include/uv.h#L1790-L1794

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it'd valid. Pre-processing of function like macros is described in the C standard by **§6.10.3 Macro replacement**. The pertinent parts are the following:

> [¶10](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3p10) ...Each subsequent instance of the function-like macro name followed
>   by a `(` as the next preprocessing token introduces the sequence of
>   preprocessing tokens that is replaced by the replacement list in the
>   definition (an invocation of the macro)....
>
> **6.10.3.1 Argument substitution**
>
> [¶1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.1p1) After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro
>   have been identified, argument substitution takes place. A parameter
>   in the replacement list, unless preceded by a # or ## preprocessing
>   token or followed by a ## preprocessing token (see below), is replaced
>   by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have
>   been expanded. Before being substituted, each argument's preprocessing
>   tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the
>   preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available.
>
> **6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement**
>
> [¶1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.4p1) After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted
>   and # and ## processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing
>   tokens are removed. The resulting preprocessing token sequence is then
>   rescanned, along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the
>   source file, for more macro names to replace.

Except for section names and numbering, the same wording exists in the C++ standard too.

So when you plug `X_LIST` in, the preprcoessor will replace `X` by it after attempting to expand `X_LIST` as though it was an object like macro. Since it's not, the tokens left with for `X` is `X_LIST`.

Then the preprocessor scans the line again. This time `X_LIST` will be followed by a `(`, and so will be expanded *now*.

Passing a function like macro's name to a "higher order function" is not unheard of. The [Boost.Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library makes heavy use of this idiom.