# Argument to macro not being substituted correctly in C

Tags: c, macros

I'm trying the code sequence below... my intent is to generate a new string  that uses the input argument of the macro as a number and treats it as an int when it does concatenation.  but looks like it's treating it as a string.  Any way to accomplish this?

```
typedef enum
{
    HELLO0BYE = 0,
    HELLO1BYE = 1,
    HELLO2BYE = 2,
    HELLO3BYE = 3,
    HELLO4BYE = 4,
    HELLO5BYE = 5,

} enum_test;

#define GEN_NEW(x) HELLO ##x## BYE
void main()
{
    enum_test input = 5;
    enum_test output;
    output = GEN_NEW(input);
}
```

Ideally I want to be able to iterate through the enums in an algorithmic way.

Comment: `number` does not have a value on the preprocessing `stage`. It's just a token for a preprocessor.

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you want?

Comment: Note that `##` should appear between to identifier-like tokens in a macro expansion.  The first `##` is erroneous.

Comment: Every time you are trying to do something like this, think: what code will be passed from the preprocessor to the compiler? Think like the preprocessor!

Comment: I wonder what you are trying to achieve. Why not simply do `output = input;` ?

Comment: Probably not representing what i'm trying to actually do..  my original enum list is a lot larger (few hundred enums)... and amongst that large list I wan't to be able to select the enum based on input parameter.  And it's not a 1:1 mapping either (input 0 doesn't equal 0 output).

Comment: @KAM In that case you should update your question to show the real problem. Anyway, as others have already said: macros are not a runtime tool.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, no you can't. But I suspect I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do.

Macro's are pre-processed. That means the macro's get substituted BEFORE your code gets compiled. So when you use the GEN_NEW macro, all the compiler knows about "number" is that it's a string. So you can't pass a run-time variable to a macro.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

When above code is processed by compiler then, we get following output:

```
# 1 "Test1.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "Test1.c"
typedef enum
{
    HELLO0BYE = 0,
    HELLO1BYE = 1,
    HELLO2BYE = 2,
    HELLO3BYE = 3,
    HELLO4BYE = 4,
    HELLO5BYE = 5,

} enum_test;


void main()
{
    enum_test input = 5;
    enum_test output;
    output = HELLOinputBYE;
}
```

When you look at above code you can see that the following line is having error:

```
output = HELLOinputBYE;
```

**Note:** To stop the the compiler after preprocessing stage use '-E' switch. I used following on gcc compiler:

```
gcc -E -o TestPreprocessedFile.txt Test1.c
```

Here 'Test1.c' is source file and 'TestPreprocessedFile.txt' is output file.

For more about gcc compiler options refer [Options Controlling the Kind of Output](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.2/gcc_2.html#SEC4)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact logic of your implementation, so I won't go into that discussion. You can use this :

```
#define CONV2STRING(X) #X
#define TO_STRING(X) CONV2STRING(X)
#define EXPAND(Y) Y
#define MERGER( X, Y) X##Y
#define MERGE( X, Y) MERGER( X, Y)

#define SAY_HELLO HELLO
#define SAY_BYE BYE

typedef enum {
    HELLO0BYE = 0,
    HELLO1BYE = 1,
    HELLO2BYE = 2,
    HELLO3BYE = 3,
    HELLO4BYE = 4,
    HELLO5BYE = 5,
} enum_test;

const static struct {
    enum_test      value;
    const char *str;
} conversion [] = {
    {HELLO0BYE, "HELLO0BYE"},
    {HELLO1BYE, "HELLO1BYE"},
    {HELLO2BYE, "HELLO2BYE"},
    {HELLO3BYE, "HELLO3BYE"},
    {HELLO4BYE, "HELLO4BYE"},
    {HELLO5BYE, "HELLO5BYE"},
};

int StringToEnum (const char *str) {
     int j;
     for (j = 0;  j < sizeof (conversion) / sizeof (conversion[0]);  ++j)
         if (!strcmp (str, conversion[j].str))
             return conversion[j].value;
     return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    enum_test output;

    #define INPUT 5
    output = StringToEnum(TO_STRING (MERGE(MERGE( SAY_HELLO, EXPAND(INPUT)), SAY_BYE)));
    printf( "Macro Expansion : %s\n", TO_STRING (MERGE(MERGE( SAY_HELLO, EXPAND(INPUT)), SAY_BYE)));
    printf("output = %d\n", output);
    #undef INPUT

    #define INPUT 4
    output = StringToEnum(TO_STRING (MERGE(MERGE( SAY_HELLO, EXPAND(INPUT)), SAY_BYE)));
    printf( "Macro Expansion : %s\n", TO_STRING (MERGE(MERGE( SAY_HELLO, EXPAND(INPUT)), SAY_BYE)));
    printf("output = %d\n", output);
    #undef INPUT
}
```

Note: I found the elegant conversion from string to enum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844728/converting-from-string-to-enum-in-c).