# Compare argv[] to list of allowable elements

Tags: c, list, enums, string-comparison

I want `myprogram` to take user-entered arguments and see if each argument matches a hard-coded list.  I am looking for a better alternative to a long `switch` statement or a series of `if else`.

Here is a minimal example of what I'm attempting using `enum`:

```
$ ./myprogram blue square

//myprogram.c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

  //many allowable colors and shapes
  enum colors_t {blue, red, /*...*/ green}; 
  enum shape_t {square, circle, /*...*/ triangle};

  //how do I check if argv[1] is on the list of colors?
  if(COMPARE(argv[1], colors_t)
    colors_t user_color = argv[1];
  else 
    printf("%s is not a usable color\n",argv[1]);

  //same question with shapes
  if(COMPARE(argv[2], shape_t)
    shape_t user_shape = argv[2];
  else  
    printf("%s is not a usable shape\n",argv[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

I need help with the `COMPARE()` function to see if `argv[i]` matches a member of its corresponding `enum` list.

Comment: A loop and an array maybe...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to use variables of enum types as string in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147267/easy-way-to-use-variables-of-enum-types-as-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use `qsort` and `bsearch` (well, if you don't mind making sure the array is sorted yourself, you don't need `qsort`). Something like (using your `enum color_t`):

```
struct color_picker {
    char const *name;
    enum colors_t id;
} acolor[] = { {"blue", blue}, {"red", red}, {"green", green} };
const unsigned acolor_count = sizeof acolor / sizeof acolor[0];

int cmp_color(struct color_picker const *l, struct color_picker const *r)
{
    return strcmp(l->name, r->name);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct color_picker *ptr;

    qsort(acolor, acolor_count, sizeof acolor[0], cmp_color);

    ptr = bsearch(name, acolor, acolor_count, sizeof acolor[0], cmp_color);
    if (NULL == ptr) {
        printf("%s is not a usable color\n",argv[1]);        }
    }
    /* the value for `enum color_t` is in `ptr->id` */

    return 0;
}
```

You could also use hash tables here, but there is not support for those in the C standard library, so you'd have to code it yourself, or use some third-party library.

Comment: I didn't use your solution, but I've upvoted and marked as accepted since you were the only one nice enough to answer.