# C++ mixing printf and cout

Tags: c++, printf, cout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mixing cout and printf for faster output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924530/mixing-cout-and-printf-for-faster-output)

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0.

The following program,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
printf("a");
printf("b");
printf("c");
return 0;
}
```

produces "abc".

While the following program,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
printf("a");
cout<<"b";
printf("c");
return 0;
}
```

produces "acb".

What's the problem? Can't I mix cout and printf in the same program?

Comment: Does [`sync_with_stdio`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) do the trick? I've never used it.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy: No it is not. The semantics of mixing wide-narrow are unspecified, whereas the semantics of the above code are well defined and it *must* print "abc" unless `sync_with_stdio(false)` was called, which does not happen here. Basically MSVC6 is non standard conforming...

Answer (score 5):

The standard says that:

> When a standard iostream object `str` is *synchronized* with a standard
>   stdio stream `f`, the effect of inserting a character `c` by
>
> ```
> fputc(f, c);
> ```
>
> is the same as the effect of
>
> ```
> str.rdbuf()->sputc(c);
> ```
>
> for any sequences of characters;

By default, unless you invoke `sync_with_stdio(false)`, `cout` is synchronized with `stdout`. Therefore your second code snippet is equivalent to:

```
printf("a");
fputc(stdout, 'b')
printf("c");
```

Which must produce "abc" even on your implementation.

Bottom line: MSVC6 is not standard conforming, which is not a surprise as it is very old.

Comment: "which is not a surprise as it is very old" - and anyways at Microsoft nobody gives a damn about standards.

Comment: @H2CO3: Not exactly true... they do work on improving their C++ compiler. In particular you cannot say that, e.g., MSVC10 is not an improvement over MSVC6.

Comment: it certainly is, but it still cannot possibly be compared with GCC or Clang...

Comment: @H2CO3 this was true for a long time. now MS is at eye level. according to our portability team MS was faster in implementing C++11

Comment: @stefan well, it might be the case with C++11, but I can't really care about C++11 until it lacks reasonable support for C99 or even C89 (which it does).

Comment: @H2CO3: You are changing the subject of the discussion. No-one here talks about C, I judge MSVC purely as a C++ compiler. In particular because I do not care for C support. Today it is so close to being a conforming C++ compiler that it is hard to compare it to GCC. Yes both have bugs, but both are good too.

Comment: @ H2CO3: my comment was addressing your comment (i cite) 'and anyways at Microsoft nobody gives a damn about standards.'

everyone may jude