# C++ not rounding as it should when using both cout and printf

Tags: c++, io

I need to make a program that calculates cos(x) and my problem is that when I use `printf` for example cos(0.2) is 0.98 but it comes out as 0.984 and it's not rounding to 2 numbers.

My code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x = 0.2;
    cout << "x=" << x << " cos(y) y=" << printf("%.2f", cos(x)) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the return value of `printf` is meant to be put in a stream.

Comment: printf returns an integer containing the number of things it wrote, but it will mess up your printing if you use printf and cout at the same time unless you are sure the buffers are syncronised.  If you do want to set the preceision in a stream you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515592/how-to-use-setprecision-in-c

Comment: either do this:
`printf("x=%f cos(y) y=%2f\n",x,cos(x));` or do this:
`cout << "x=" << x << " cos(y) y=" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << cos(x) << "\n";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, mixing `std::cout` and `printf` does not do what you want. Instead use the stream manipulators `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision`:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>  //Required for std::fixed and std::precision
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath> //Notice corrected include, this is the C++ version of <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x = 0.2f; //Initialize with a float instead of silently converting from a double to a float.
    cout << "x=" << x << " cos(y) y=" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << cos(x) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not with rounding the numbers, but with output.

> ```
> cout << "x=" << x << " cos(y) y=" << printf("%.2f", cos(x)) << "\n";
> ```

Here you are mixing two ways to write to the standard output. Inserting a call to `printf` into `cout <<` will output the *return value* of `printf` which happens to be `4` and at the same time output something as a side effect.

So two outputs are created:

- Streaming values into `cout` outputs `x=0.2 cos(y) y=4`
- Calling `printf` (correctly) outputs `0.98`

It is possible that the two outputs are mingled with each other, creating the impression that the result was `0.984`:

```
x=0.2 cos(y) y=    4
               ^^^^
               0.98
```

You *can* use both `cout` and `printf`, but you should not confuse the *return value* of `printf` with the output it creates as a *side effect*:

```
cout << "x=" << x << " cos(y) y=";
printf("%.2f\n", cos(x));
```

should output

```
x=0.2 cos(y) y=0.98
```

See also: [C++ mixing printf and cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667397/c-mixing-printf-and-cout)

Comment: (note that it would make more sense mathematically to just output `cos(x)=0.98` and not `cos(y) y=0.98`)