# What is wrong with this char array to std::string conversion?

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to convert a `char` array to an `std::string`, but I only get gibberish in the `std::string`. What is wrong?

```
char char_buff[40];
sprintf_s(char_buff, 40, "test" );
printf("%s\n", char_buff); // prints "test"

std::string str(char_buff);
printf("%s\n", str); // prints random nonsense
```

Comment: Do you mean `str.c_str()`? It will give you a pointer to a C-style string.

Comment: problem with printf("%s\n", str); not the string try printf("%s\n", str.c_str());

Comment: thanks, should have tried with normally initializing the string

Comment: `printf("%s\n", str.c_str())`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Passing a `std::string` to `printf` gives undefined behavior.

When you try to print out the `string` instance, try using `std::cout` instead:

```
char char_buff[40];
sprintf_s(char_buff, 40, "test" );
std::cout << char_buff << "\n";

std::string str(char_buff);
std::cout << str << "\n";
```

Comment: You should also explain how to use it with printf

Comment: @NeilKirk: No, I shouldn't. While it's *possible* to use `printf` in C++, it's almost never a good idea.

Comment: That's very judgemental. printf is still part of C++. I didn't say remove your advice about cout.

Comment: @NeilKirk Judgemental is relative.  `printf` is so totally broken that I'd avoid it even in C.

Comment: `printf` is faster then `cout`. So it it should be used in c++ program if output speed is essential.

Comment: @JamesKanze How is it "totally broken"? I know it is vulnerable to issues such as bad control strings. But so long as the parameters are correct, it works fine.

Comment: @Ashot: Speed of cout vs. printf varies widely. At one time, it was true that iostreams were consistently enough slower than C-style I/O that it was at least worth considering. That was a couple of decades ago though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I still find C-style file is faster than C++ fstream on VS2013 for heavy duty use

Comment: @NeilKirk: Then you're probably doing something wrong. The most common problem I've seen is unnecessary use of `std::endl`. FWIW, a test I ran years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1926432/179910

Comment: I am referring only to file streams.

Comment: @JerryCoffin How is printf "totally broken"?

Comment: @Andreas: I'm not the one who said it was totally broken, but a few obvious shortcoming include: 1) it's not type-safe (as you demonstrated) 2) it's not extensible 3) non-default formatting is compact but often quite unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> std::string str(char_buff);
> printf("%s\n", str); // prints random nonsense
> ```

The problem is that `%s` makes `printf()` expect a `const char*`; in other words, `%s` is a *placeholder* for `const char*`.

Instead, you passed `str`, which is an instance of `std::string`, *not* a `const char*`.

To fix that, just use the **`c_str()`** method of `std::string`:

```
printf("%s\n", str.c_str());
```

`c_str()` returns a C-style pointer to a `NUL`-terminated string, as expected from C functions like `printf()`.

---

As a side note:

> ```
> char char_buff[40];
> sprintf_s(char_buff, 40, "test" );
> ```

Note that `sprintf_s()` can be used in a simpler form, making it to automatically deduce the destination buffer length, thanks to some template "magic":

```
sprintf_s(char_buff, "test");  // char_buff size automatically deduced
```

See this `sprintf_s()` template from [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k(v=vs.100).aspx):

> ```
> template <size_t size>
> int sprintf_s(
>    char (&buffer)[size],
>    const char *format [,
>    argument] ... 
> ); // C++ only
> ```

Comment: Sorry, but "To fix that, just use the `c_str()` method of `std::string` is truly *lousy* advice.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Sorry, but your comment is _lousy_. If the guy wants to use `printf()` in C++ code, then he's free to do that, and to make `std::string` interop with `printf()` to my knowledge calling `c_str()` is just fine.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Stupid comparison. There are several C++ programmers that use C `<stdio.h>` in their C++ code, and there is no "shoot in the foot". On the same note, I could say you are "shooting yourself in the foot" using C++ I/O streams that are much slower and inefficient if compared to C `<stdio.h>`. If you don't want to use `printf()` that's fine, but the question is about making `std::string` correctly interoperating with `printf()`. The OP is free to choose `printf()` or `std::cout`. Being respectful of other people's ideas is fundamental in a sane community.

Comment: I simply don't read the question as being about making `std::string` correctly interoperate with `printf`. I read it as being about converting a char array to `std::string`. I guess I should have read the: "What is wrong with this char array to std::string conversion?", more carefully to find the reference to `printf`. And no, as noted elsewhere, `printf` really isn't faster than iostreams either. "A sane community" doesn't require that I agree with your lavish praise of the emperor's new clothes.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: In a sane community people can have different ideas, but they should respect each others, even if they disagree. I've spent enough time with stupid non-sensical comments including this last thing on the "emperor's clothes" (are you projecting something?). So I close this thing now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59116/discussion-between-jerry-coffin-and-mr-c64).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, printf is an old c function and is not type safe. It just interprets the given arguments as you tell it to.

By using the `%s` as the first occurring format specifier [you tell printf to interpret](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) the first argument as a `char *`, causing gibberish to be printed.

In order to have the contents of the string be printed you need to get to the char* data that the std::string wraps. You can do this using [.c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).