# How can I clip trailing spaces from output

Tags: c++, string, stdout

Ok, so by reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792812/the-backspace-escape-character-b-in-c-unexpected-behavior) I've understood what `\b` and `\n` do exactly. I still don't know how to do the following:

I need to print all elements of an array separated by a space, then do some operation on that array and print another set of all elements from the array, a number of times, with each set separated by a newline. Something like this:

```
x[0] x[1] x[2] x[n]
x[0] x[1] x[2] x[n]
x[0] x[1] x[2] x[n]
(etc.)
```

This is my code:

```
std::printf("%f ",t);
for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
    std::printf("%f ", x[i]);
}
std::printf("\b\n");
```

However this leaves a trailing space at the end of each line. How can I make the output be `"x[0] x[1] x[n]\nx[0] x[1] x[n]\n(...)"` instead of `"x[0] x[1] x[n] \nx[0] x[1] x[n] \n(...)"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you're printing the last number before printing the space after the number:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    std::printf("%f", x[i]);
    if (i != N-1) {
        std::putc(' ');
    }
}
```

If your benchmarks show that the comparisons are the bottleneck, rather than I/O, you can split up the loop and handle the last case separately:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
    std::printf("%f ", x[i]);
}
if (i < N) {
    std::printf("%f", x[i]);
}
```

Comment: Well, this does the job but I'm writing a high performance program and this printing cycle is inserted in a loop that iterates tens of millions of times, with the array having 20-30 elements , so this means a number of comparisons in the order of 10^8 to 10^9. Maybe it's silly and it's actually insignificant, but I'm worried about the performance impact.

Comment: Compared to the actual I/O overhead, the comparisons are negligible.

Comment: Bingo. This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks. (couldn't the if block be just `std::printf("%f", x[N]);`?)

Comment: It should be `std::printf("%f", x[N-1]);`. But if `N == 0`, the array is empty so there's nothing to print.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use an [`infix_ostream_iterator`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489).

Using that, the code becomes fairly simple:

```
#include "infix_iterator"

std::cout << t << " ";
std::copy(x.begin(), x.end(), infix_ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << "\n";
```

Comment: Again, I'm worried about the performance impact of using that wrapper vs naked C.

Comment: @andrepd: At least based on my [testing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1926432/179910), your worry is probably unwarranted.

Answer (score 1):

Add a space only when you are not writing the last element.

```
std::printf("%f ",t);
for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
    std::printf("%f", x[i]);
    if ( i != N-1 )
    {
       std::printf(" ");
    }
}
std::printf("\n");
```

Comment: Well, this does the job but I'm writing a high performance program and this printing cycle is inserted in a loop that iterates tens of millions of times, with the array having 20-30 elements , so this means a number of comparisons in the order of 10^8 to 10^9. Maybe it's silly and it's actually insignificant, but I'm worried about the performance impact.

Comment: The bottleneck will definitely be disk IO, not the comparison code. Give it a shot and see what you find.

Comment: Actually, replacing my code with yours makes it go *faster*, 2.5s vs 1.8s for a small number of iterations. o.O

Comment: Nevermind I accidentally omitted compiler flags on one case. Difference is unmeasurable on this scale.