# Why output is printed not in the console output C++

Tags: c++, c++17, mingw

So I was running a simple C++ code containing this piece

```
freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
for(int k=i;k--;k>=1)
{
    if(outgoing[k]=='Y' && incoming[k-1]=='Y')
        result[i][k-1]='Y';
    else
        break;
}
```

So usually the error if there is any it printed into console output but while running this code it printed this error inside the output file

```
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:1067:
 std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::reference
 std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,
 _Alloc>::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>;
 std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::reference =
 char&; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type
 = unsigned int]: Assertion '__pos <= size()' failed.
```

I don't understand why? And who is Keith?

I know the error by the way here
`for(int k=i;k--;k>=1)` k-- and k>=1 should be swapped

Comment: The assertion says you gave it a bad index to `operator[]`.  Make sure `k` is a valid index for the string you are accesing, i.e., `k < string.size()`

Comment: Seems that you are accessing Keith's compiler.

Comment: @john I am not accessing Keith's computer

Comment: @NathanOliver so I think as while checking first time k=0 and when it processes k-- so value becomes k=-1 and its still will result in running the loop. So It will be a bad index . Thanks

Comment: But still why the output is redirected to output.txt file? And is mingw contains this "Keith" keyword?

Comment: @SauravKumarSingh Well I said compiler not computer.

Comment: @SauravKumarSingh Uh, you ask to redirect output to file here: `freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);`. And that's just a filepath, apparently your MinGW is installed in `/home/keith`. If you have multiple installations on your computer (like one for you and one for Keith), you may need to point to correct one, but that's a different question (it's related to your build system, not to C++ code itself).

Comment: _"And who is Keith?"_ 

Comment: Did you build MinGW from source, or did Keith build it for you (and you just installed the binaries that Keith made)?  (That's probably Keith Marshall.)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen This info _should_ go to stderr...

Comment: Provide a [mcve] including build and execution commands.

Comment: Keith is not the username I use or anyone use on my computer. And my only question is why this error is reproduced to the output file as i mentioned clearly `stdout` in the code

Comment: Are you mixing cout and stdout?   see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1924530/2785528

Comment: @2785528 No mixing.

Comment: "keith" was the username under which the C++ standard library that you are using was built. The library code likely uses `assert` macro or similar, which in turn uses `__FILE__`, which captured the file name as it existed on the build machine at build time.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are reading characters from a string or file, you have to make sure your loop ends before the string or file reaches `\n` or `EOF`.

This can be verified by the compiler only if you mention bounds for the string or file which is known to compiler.

So instead of running the loop until `k>=1` maybe you can use a `while` loop or maybe `str.length()` where str is a string variable.

And maybe Keith is someone who was involved in writing the mingw compiler.