# C++ Size of Array

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sizeof array passed as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter)

I am being stupid with this sizeof operator in c++, do you have any idea why it is 4 and 12 ?

```
 void function (int arg[]) {
        cout<<sizeof(arg)<<endl; // 4
    }

    int main ()
    {
        int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
        cout<<sizeof array<<endl; // 12
        function (array);
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: [Sizeof array passed as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720077/calculating-size-of-an-array - this is a FAQ.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In `main`, the name `array` is an array so you get the size in bytes of the array with `sizeof`. However, an array decays to a pointer when passed to a function, so you get `sizeof(int*)` inside the function.

Be aware that taking an argument in the form of `T arg[]` is *exactly* the same as taking the argument as `T* arg`. So your function is the exact equivalent of

```
void function(int* arg) {
    cout << sizeof(arg) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 void function (int arg[]) // or void function (int arg[N])
```

is equivalent to

```
 void function (int *arg)
```

thus,

```
sizeof(arg) == sizeof(int*)
```

If you intend to pass array itself, then C++ offers you to pass it by reference:

```
void function (int (&arg)[3])
              //   ^^^ pass by reference
```

Now,

```
sizeof(arg) == sizeof(int[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program below is similar to the next one.

```
void function (int arg[]) {
    cout<<sizeof(arg)<<endl; // 4
}
```

Program below prints the size of pointer.

```
void function (int *arg) {
    cout<<sizeof(arg)<<endl; // 4
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are simply pointers to an arbitrary amount of memory. If you do sizeof(array) it will return the size of a pointer - 4 bytes on 32 bit systems, and 8 bytes on 64 bit systems (if the program is compiled as 64 bit).

This is the same reason that you have to null-terminate your strings in c/c++ - to denote the end of the array.

Simply put, you have the keep track of the size of your arrays yourself. If you allocate an array of 40 bytes, you have to make sure you never access the array above the 40th index (ie. array[39]).

Hope this helps.

Comment: If arrays are simply pointers, how come inside `main` it prints 12?

Comment: I can't be 100% sure, but my guess is because your array is static. It's size is determined at compile-time, unlike dynamic memory. Sizeof() may work on static arrays, but i can assure you it won't work on arrays that are allocated dynamically during runtime.

Comment: arrays are not simply pointers.

Comment: @xaxxon Yes, they are when it comes right down to it. An array is a pointer to an area of memory containing a sequence of a specified datatype.

Comment: @Gogeta70 An array is a language construct which is distinct from and behaves differently than a pointer.   A pointer is also a language construct.   Both may contain a memory address, but neither is "simply" the other and both have unique behaviors within the language.

Comment: @xaxxon I'm afraid you're mistaken. Write a simple C/C++ program that uses an array and then open the resulting executable in a disassembler. You'll see the code for your array is treated the same as a pointer at the assembly level.

Comment: @Gogeta70 I was simply trying to point out the difference between a language construct and the resulting generated code.  From a language perspective "arrays are simply pointers" is clearly false.   That was all I was saying.   What the linker generates is orthogonal to how the language handles them.  Perhaps the context of the question makes your answer sufficiently correct, but many people are confused when they hear "arrays are just pointers" too often and then expect the langauge to treat them the same as well.

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:c++]. In C++, arrays are decidedly different entities from pointers. Arrays can *decay* into pointers, when passed to functions. But you can also pass arrays by reference. Change the code to `template <size_t N> void function(int (&arg)[N]) { ... }` and [observe the result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7288803105da5a8). With that it should be easy to understand, why people think this answer is wrong.