# What is the value of X and Y ?.why it is different?

Tags: c++, output

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int function(int arr [])
{
  int y = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
  return y;
}

int main ()
{
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

  int x = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

  cout <<x<<"\n";

  int y=function(arr);

  cout <<y<<"\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what output are you getting?

Comment: `[]` in a function parameter does not mean an array, it means a pointer.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - in my opionion, om gupta wants write a function where the calculation of the array length is done via a function and I do not know a way how to do that. I would say, this is not possible, because the calculation is done in the preprocessor. Am I correct?

Comment: @Mat how did you add the `This question already has an answer here:`, I found another very good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162923/calculate-length-of-array-in-c-by-using-function

Comment: @lx42.de it's not possible. The calculation is not done by the preprocessor either.

Comment: @lx42.de, the message at the top is automatically added by Stack Overflow when the question is closed for being a duplicate of another one.

Answer (score 1):

```
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  int x = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

In this case `arr` is an array of 6 int elements. `sizeof` of an `int` is 4 bytes, thus `sizeof(arr)` is 24, divided by `sizeof` of a single int equals 6.

```
int function(int arr [])
{
  int y = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
  return y;
}
```

In this case `arr` decays to a pointer to an int. Depending on your platform, `sizeof` of a pointer might be 4 or 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The output will be as follows:

```
6
1
```

#### Explanation:

When you compute `x` inside the `main()` function, `arr` is an array. Therefore, `sizeof(arr)` returns the size of the whole array in bytes.

```
int x = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
// 24 / 4 = 6 (assuming your compiler assigns 4 bytes to an integer)
```

But when you pass the same to a function, what gets passed as the parameter is the pointer to the array. So, this is essentially like passing `int *arr` to the function.

Source: [C++ Size of Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509829/c-size-of-array)

Comment: I got 6 and 2 on cygwin: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows. My integers are 64bit/8 Byte long.