# Find size of input char* and copy portion to output char* C

Tags: c, pointers, char, sizeof

I have a char array `LL,4014.84954` that I send into a function like this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void myFunction(char* in_string, char* out_string) {
  printf("Start_String=%s\n", in_string);
  int in_size = (int)(sizeof(in_string));
  printf("%d\n", in_size);
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i <= in_size-ceil(in_size/2); i++) {
    out_string[i] = in_string[i];
  }
}

int main(int arg) {
  char in_string[] = "LL,4014.84954";
  char out_string[] = "";
  printf("In_String=%s\n", in_string);
  myFunction(in_string, out_string);
  printf("Out_String=%s\n", out_string);
}
```

My question has two parts.

1. How do I get the length of this char array? `int in_size = (int)(sizeof(in_string));` in this example gives me 8 which is the size of the pointer (long int). I know I could make a for loop that marches through until it see the null termination, but is there a nicer way? I previously was using char[] and `sizeof` works great, but now I am converting to char*.
2. How can I write a portion of these chars to `out_string`. My example currently writes all chars to `out_string`.

Here is the raw output:

```
In_String=LL,4014.84954
Start_String=LL,4014.84954
8
Out_String=LL,40014.84954
```

Comment: Using the `sizeof()` a *pointer* probably isn't helping your cause. You may want to review [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720077/calculating-size-of-an-array) along with the answers below.

Comment: What portion of the chars? If it's just from a set offset to the end, it's very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)**
Answer to question 2:

```
char out_string[] = "";
```

`out_string[]` is of only one size. you assigning  `out_string[i] = ...` for `i > 0` is wrong and cause an undefined error. Instead of this you should declare `out_string[]` like this:

```
out_string[] = malloc(strlen(in_string) + 1);

//                                        ^ extra for \0 char
```

**(2)**
additionally @WhozCraig  commenting correct, you actually need `strlen()` to find length of string. sizeof you are using wrong.

So replace:

```
int in_size = (int)(sizeof(in_string));
```

by

```
int in_size = strlen(in_string);
```

**(3)**
Also, what is `in_size-ceil`. As I can understands from your raw output you don't need such kind of function and calculations. Just replace your for loop:

```
for(i = 0; i <= in_size-ceil(in_size/2); i++)
```

by

```
for(i = 0; i < in_size; i++)
```

**(4)**
At the end don;t forget to terminate you `string out_string`, after for loop add this line

```
out_string[i] = '\0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, use [`strlen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strlen.html).

Regarding the second question, first of all you need to make sure that `out_string` is wide enough to accommodate the result. Currently, it isn't, and the behaviour of your code is undefined. Once you fix that, to copy a portion of the string you'd need to change the initial and final conditions of the `for` loop, not forgetting about the NUL terminator.

Comment: And `strlen` is a well debugged implementation of walking along the string until you encounter a `\0`. That's one of the costs of using `<special character> terminated` strings instead of `(length, buffer)` strings as for instance pascal does.