# Creating C# attribute that hooks into property's getter and setter

Tags: c#, attributes, aop

As a part of my API, I have an abstract BaseEntity class. I would like to provide a way to somehow hook into new properties that are introduced in the descendants of this class. What I was thinking is this:

```
public class MyEntity : BaseEntity
{
    [DataElement]
    public int NewProperty { get; set; }
}
```

If I could write an attribute `DataElement` that would hook in the getter and setter, then my API would be made aware of this property on access.

Is this possible?

**UPD:** I'll try to explain where this comes from. I have this BaseEntity that does not have any data by itself. Its descendants will declare what data they may hold as properties. I want to be able to iterate through all the data the object has (to store it in the database in a very specific form). One way to do it is reflection. But I thought about doing it via attributes that would register the data whenever the property is accessed.

Comment: Look at PostSharp: http://www.postsharp.net

Comment: I think what you need is here

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733428/override-property-setter-and-getter/21733564#21733564][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733428/override-property-setter-and-getter/21733564#21733564

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob added an update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, it would look similar to the following:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class DataElementAttribute : Attribute 
{ }
```

You will have to enumerate the properties with reflection to see if the property contains the attribute.  (which begs the question, do you really need the attribute).

```
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            IList<PropertyInfo> properties = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
            {
                if (type.IsDefined(typeof(DataElementAttribute), false))
                {
                    // Perform Logic
                }
            }
        }
```

However injecting Logic into the setter is a different task which would need to be done post compilation:  [Why is post-compilation code injection a better idea than pre-compilation code injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210735/why-is-post-compilation-code-injection-a-better-idea-than-pre-compilation-code-i)

Injecting MSIL is not easy.  Take a peek at this example code:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer

Comment: I was thinking that whenever the property gets written to, I also add the data into a protected dictionary. One way to do this is to explicitly call a method inside the property. I thought I could also *hook* into the setter using an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could force inheritors to specify how the object should be saved/loaded by adding a couple of abstract methods.

Example, inspired by the `ISerializable` interface:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public void SaveToDatabase()
    {
        var objectData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        this.GetObjectData(objectData);
        DatabaseManager.Save(objectData);
    }

    public void LoadFromDatabase(Dictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        this.SetObjectData(data);
    }

    protected abstract void GetObjectData(Dictionary<string, object> data);

    protected abstract void SetObjectData(Dictionary<string, object> data);
}

public class MyEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public int NewProperty { get; set; }

    protected override void GetObjectData(Dictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        data.Add("NewProperty", this.NewProperty);
    }

    protected override void SetObjectData(Dictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        this.NewProperty = (int)data["NewProperty"];
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this sort of approach is that it becomes hard to maintain it when adding new data parts.

Comment: You could also make the `Get/SetObjectData` methods virtual instead of abstract, and provide a default implementation that uses reflection to get/set the property values.