# Inline functions and conditional compiling in VB.NET or C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Does VisualBasic.NET or C# support conditional compiling? And inline functions (macros)?

When I talk about conditional compiling, I mean something like C/C++, where you do:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    my_var = call_some_debug_function();
#else
    my_var = call_some_final_function();
#endif
```

And in the resulting compiled code, there is only the call to the `call_some_debug_function` or the `call_some_final_function`.

When I talk about inline functions, I mean something like C/C++ macros:

```
#define sum(a, b) a + b
...
total = sum(a, b)
```

And the resulting compiled code is:

```
total = a + b
```

Are these constructions supported by any of these .NET languages?

Comment: Here's a question with answers explaining *why* C# doesn't support macros: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369725/why-arent-there-macros-in-c

Comment: You can cause a lot more havoc with macros in C and C++, C# certainly does not allow defining a buggy function style macro like that.  But inlining optimization is not fundamentally different, the end result in machine code it is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditional compilation is supported by both C# and VB:

[C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx):

```
#if DEBUG
   Foo();
#else
   Bar();
#endif
```

[VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx6yas69.aspx):

```
#If DEBUG Then
   Foo
#Else
   Bar
#End If
```

Macros are not supported in C# or VB as far as I'm aware... typically inlining is left to the JIT compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works but it's more something like:

```
#if DEBUG
    my_var = call_some_debug_function();
#else
    my_var = call_some_final_function();
#endif
```