# UI programming in Visual Studio 2010 using C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, forms, visual-c++

I want to program in Visual Studio 2010. My choice of programming language is C++. 
I want to know what project shall I select when I click on new project? I understand that a solution is a collection of projects.

I believe I need to select Win32 Project type as selected in following snap shot.

[image]

When I create new projects, I get a directory structure which includes following folders:
1. External dependencies
2. Header files
3. Resource files
4. Source files

I want to understand following things:

1. How and where to edit UI screen? I tried playing around with the project and I want not able to understand from where to get to a screen in IDE where I can create forms, buttons, text boxes, etc.
   I know that we can add dialog boxes (forms) in Resource View. But is it the only way to do the same? How to find associated back-end code?
   What will be a good reference material to go through to understand these concepts?
2. If there are more than one project in the solution that is created, how do they depend on each other?
3. I have seen some example codes. And there I have seen statements like    `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()` written without semi-colon at the end. I want to know what does it mean? From where can I understand the basic architecture to be followed while creating a similar project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be looking for MFC (and documentation thereof). Be warned that MFC is extremely old and widely despised -- if you're going to do UI code in C++, you might want to consider something like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) instead.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Actually I would be editing a legacy code written in MFC then. So, I need to learn the same.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to start with a [good introductory C++ textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1) before you delve into more complicated things. Once you've learnt the basics, consider following Jerry's advice. If you're not at a point where you even know how to start a project in Visual Studio, or [what a macro is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96196/when-are-c-macros-beneficial), you're probably not ready for something like MFC.

Answer (score 1):

In VC++ if you want to start with UI, start with MFC project.
Based on your need you can create Document view or dialog based project.

If you have created dialog based project there is a resource view where you can see default dialog you want to modify and you can see widgets(buttin , editbox, etc) toolbox on selecting dialog view.

developing MFC app doesen't vary much from visual studio 2010 to any other version.
you can get the basic understanding from following tutorial.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb693459.aspx